# How to add an onClick event on a React Component that is passed down to another component as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm trying to create a `trigger` component that I can pass down to another component. And I want to be able to add a click event on that `trigger` component from the receiving component.

here is a playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xxmz6h?file=index.tsx

this is what I tried

code

```
const ComponentA = ({ children, Trigger }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Trigger
        onClick={(): void => {
          console.log('click');
          setShow(true);
        }}
      />
      {show && children}
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentB = (): JSX.Element => {
  return <button>Click me</button>;
};


<ComponentA Trigger={ComponentB}>
  <div>it worked</div>
</ComponentA>
```

I was expecting that on clicking the rendered button to log `click` and update the state. which would in turn render the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed the `onClick` prop to `ComponentB`, but you forgot to pass the `onClick` prop to the `<button>` component. See [Responding to Events](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events)

```
import React from 'react';

const ComponentB = ({ onClick }): JSX.Element => {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>;
};

export default ComponentB;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-s5bu6v?file=ComponentB.tsx)

Comment: missed that. thank you!